# Connect to salesforce and add data to some object without your login credential

Tags: apex, force.com, administration, app, form

I am researching some form builder in salesforce.Then I found the fast Form application and install it. After creating new form in which the fields are connected to specific salesforce object, the app gives a javascript wherein we can embed in a third party site or even in localhost. After embedding the code given let say for example in my localhost, you can view the form in your localhost. When you insert some data in it, the data will be automatically saved to salesforce. I was amazed how those things worked. My question is, is it possible to connect to salesforce without login credentials and insert data to a salesforce ? If yes, how ? Please help thank you.

Comment: There's plenty of ways to get data into salesforce from a generic form on the web. You could compose an email to an email service, set up a Site to collect information by a public API or Visualforce page, secure an OAuth token on a proxy server that uses the API for you, etc. If I could see an example of the form, I might have a better idea of what's going on, but as it is, this question is a bit open-ended.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sorry if the question is too broad. But thank you. maybe I will just search your suggestions.

Comment: which object you are referring ? if its Case or lead object then there is feature called Web to case and web to lead which allows you to insert cases or lead in SFDC without authentication. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&language=en   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm&language=en

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 any object. Actually it is choosen during the creation of forms. I was just amazed because after the creation of forms, it will give a javascript that can be embedded in another website. And you can already add data from it without signing in.

Comment: Can you add the javascript to your question?